# vaadin project is not running in netbeans

Tags: java, vaadin

I am new to vaadin and when I tried to create a new project, this problem occurred ...I looked on google, but can't find any solution

pdating theme VAADIN\themes\mytheme
Error: Could not find or load main class com.vaadin.server.themeutils.SASSAddonImportFileCreator
Updating theme "VAADIN\themes\mytheme" failed
org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.JavaCommandException: Command [[
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\java -Xmx512m -classpath E:\college\NetBeansProjects\firtvadin\src\main\webapp;E:\college\NetBeansProjects\firtvadin\target\classes;E:\college\NetBeansProjects\firtvadin\src\main\java;C:\Users\sahadev.m2\repository\javax\servlet\javax.servlet-api\3.0.1\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar;C:\Users\sahadev.m2\repository\com\vaadin\vaadin-server\7.7.9\vaadin-server-7.7.9.jar;C:\Users\sahadev.m2\repository\com\vaadin\vaadin-sass-compiler\0.9.13\vaadin-sass-compiler-0.9.13.jar;C:\Users\sahadev.m2\repository\org\w3c\css\sac\1.3\sac-1.3.jar;C:\Users\sahadev.m2\repository\com\vaadin\external\flute\flute\1.3.0.gg2\flute-1.3.0.gg2.jar;C:\Users\sahadev.m2\repository\com\vaadin\vaadin-shared\7.7.9\vaadin-shared-7.7.9.jar;C:\Users\sahadev.m2\repository\org\jsoup\jsoup\1.8.3\jsoup-1.8.3.jar;C:\Users\sahadev.m2\repository\com\vaadin\vaadin-push\7.7.9\vaadin-push-7.7.9.jar;C:\Users\sahadev.m2\repository\com\vaadin\external\atmosphere\atmosphere-runtime\2.2.9.vaadin2\atmosphere-runtime-2.2.9.vaadin2.jar;C:\Users\sahadev.m2\repository\com\vaadin\external\slf4j\vaadin-slf4j-jdk14\1.6.1\vaadin-slf4j-jdk14-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\sahadev.m2\repository\com\vaadin\vaadin-client-compiled\7.7.9\vaadin-client-compiled-7.7.9.jar;C:\Users\sahadev.m2\repository\com\vaadin\vaadin-themes\7.7.9\vaadin-themes-7.7.9.jar com.vaadin.server.themeutils.SASSAddonImportFileCreator E:\college\NetBeansProjects\firtvadin\src\main\webapp\VAADIN\themes\mytheme
]] failed with status 1
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.JavaCommand.execute(JavaCommand.java:327)
    at com.vaadin.integration.maven.UpdateThemeMojo.processTheme(UpdateThemeMojo.java:45)
    at com.vaadin.integration.maven.AbstractThemeMojo.doExecute(AbstractThemeMojo.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.AbstractGwtShellMojo.execute(AbstractGwtShellMojo.java:182)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)

### at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)

### BUILD FAILURE

Total time: 4.665s
Finished at: Sat Jun 03 23:53:27 NPT 2017

### Final Memory: 14M/178M

Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:7.7.9:update-theme (default) on project firtvadin: Updating theme "VAADIN\themes\mytheme" failed: Command [[
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\java -Xmx512m -classpath E:\college\NetBeansProjects\firtvadin\src\main\webapp;E:\college\NetBeansProjects\firtvadin\target\classes;E:\college\NetBeansProjects\firtvadin\src\main\java;C:\Users\sahadev.m2\repository\javax\servlet\javax.servlet-api\3.0.1\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar;C:\Users\sahadev.m2\repository\com\vaadin\vaadin-server\7.7.9\vaadin-server-7.7.9.jar;C:\Users\sahadev.m2\repository\com\vaadin\vaadin-sass-compiler\0.9.13\vaadin-sass-compiler-0.9.13.jar;C:\Users\sahadev.m2\repository\org\w3c\css\sac\1.3\sac-1.3.jar;C:\Users\sahadev.m2\repository\com\vaadin\external\flute\flute\1.3.0.gg2\flute-1.3.0.gg2.jar;C:\Users\sahadev.m2\repository\com\vaadin\vaadin-shared\7.7.9\vaadin-shared-7.7.9.jar;C:\Users\sahadev.m2\repository\org\jsoup\jsoup\1.8.3\jsoup-1.8.3.jar;C:\Users\sahadev.m2\repository\com\vaadin\vaadin-push\7.7.9\vaadin-push-7.7.9.jar;C:\Users\sahadev.m2\repository\com\vaadin\external\atmosphere\atmosphere-runtime\2.2.9.vaadin2\atmosphere-runtime-2.2.9.vaadin2.jar;C:\Users\sahadev.m2\repository\com\vaadin\external\slf4j\vaadin-slf4j-jdk14\1.6.1\vaadin-slf4j-jdk14-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\sahadev.m2\repository\com\vaadin\vaadin-client-compiled\7.7.9\vaadin-client-compiled-7.7.9.jar;C:\Users\sahadev.m2\repository\com\vaadin\vaadin-themes\7.7.9\vaadin-themes-7.7.9.jar com.vaadin.server.themeutils.SASSAddonImportFileCreator E:\college\NetBeansProjects\firtvadin\src\main\webapp\VAADIN\themes\mytheme
]] failed with status 1
-> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to clear the target folder from your project folder? Sometimes it works for me.